# How to create a new object in the .connect function with pyqt?

Tags: python, oop, pyqt5

I want to create a new object of the Class Lamp with the name of the clicked item.

```
self.listWidget_lamps.clicked.connect(Hue = Lamp(name_item))
```

Since this is not working, I would like to now what the right way looks like and how I need to inherit the Lamp class to the `class Ui_MainWindow(object):`.

Here is my code (issue line 52):
https://pastebin.com/rjg96kuJ

Here is the init of the class Lamps:

```
class Lamp:
    """Class to control phillips hue lamps/groups"""

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
        with open("data.json", "r") as self.file:
            self.data = json.load(self.file)
        self.brightness = self.data["lamps"][self.name]["brightness"]
        self.xy = self.data["lamps"][self.name]["color"]
```

Comment: Note: you should *never* try to manually edit pyuic files. Read more about the proper way to deal with those files in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input into `...cliked.connect()` has to be a function - something that can be called with a pair of brackets. So `Hue = ...` will not work. Instead, use a lambda function or a function you have defined. Also note that to get the name of an item you should use `...itemClicked.connect()` not `...clicked.connect()` which passes the item clicked as a parameter to the function. This is (I believe) the shortest way of doing it, although very unreadable and not recommended:

```py
self.listWidget_lamps.itemClicked.connect(lambda item: globals().update({"Hue": Lamp(item.text())}))
```

This is the recommended way:

```py
Hue = None
def new_lamp(item):
    global Hue
    Hue = Lamp(item.text())
self.listWidget_lamps.itemClicked.connect(new_lamp)
```

Comment: Thanks!

I implemented it like this at the beginning and line 43, but everytime I click on a element of the listwidget it crashes...

Could you please help me?

https://pastebin.com/e3yiqzN6

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you paste the error message here?

Comment: It's hard to tell without the error message but I think the problem might lie in the fact that you are using `...clicked.connect()` not `...itemClicked.connect()`. Try using that instead.